# A 3rd grade math problem: fill in blanks with numbers to obtain a valid equation

Tags: algorithms, diophantine-equations, recreational-mathematics, puzzle, recursive-algorithms

Even though this is a 3rd-grade math problem, people found it extremely hard. Any people have a solution, or algorithm is welcome. I'll try make a program base on the algorithm and see if it's correct. And, people are welcome to provide the best solution (least loop, recursion)

Enough said, here's the original: Fill in the blank the number from 1-9 to complete the equation. (probably distinct numbers each blank)

[image]

PS: Help me with tags. I'm not sure which tags should I use.

EDIT 1: After a few shortened, here's what I've got:

```
a + d - f + 12*e + 13*b/c + g*h/j = 87.
```

So, as you see, the priority does matter.

EDIT 2: Maybe my description is not clear enough, but I think it require to use every number

Like this: an array from [1:9], each fill in the blank remove one component.
As Martigan point out, it's like: fill in the blanks using once and only once each number from 1 to 9. Simple math here: There are 9*8*7*6*5*4*3*2 = 362880 possibilitities. (You may correct this simple math if I'm wrong).

And b mod c should = 0 (as only integers appear.)

EDIT 3: I just asked my mom (who's an elementary teacher). She's confirmed that 3rd grade has studied about mathematic priority, so sorry Hagen von Eitzen. Your answer is half right, she'd give you an 7/10.

PS2: People, please share your wisdom and provide the math algorithm.

Sorry for my bad English.

Comment: What does the colon : mean in those two boxes?

Comment: Why not just put a zero in every box except that last (empty) one and make that one $76$?

Comment: It's divide. X = multiple, : = divide. + = Plus. - = Minus.

Comment: Even if you did that, it's doesn't equal to the end. I'll edit the question.

Comment: You have many many possible solutions. I don't see the point of the problem? Do you want a specific solution? What is the criterai to put forward as a measure of success?

Comment: There are nine unknowns, $x_1,\dots,x_{9}$.  Here's a possible solution: $x_1=76$,  $x_2=x_4=x_5=x_6=x_7=x_8=0$, $x_3=1$, $x_{9}=1$.

Comment: $76$ $0$ $1$ $0$ $0$ $0$ $0$ $1$ $1$ is a solution. Grilled by @Gregory Rant

Comment: 1 -> 9 means 9 unknowns. Only 362880 try (because distinct numbers). But only of them true.

Comment: As a general comment, you can reduce the problem by stating all products to 0, and keep only one positive and one negative term ($a$,$f$)... You can do what you want then.

Comment: I would like to have an algorithm to this problem, with have the least loop as possible.

Comment: @Eddie Thanks I fixed it

Comment: Do you want to use once and only once each number from 1 to 9? This would be a different and trickier problem.

Comment: Probably that is. It's not that easy to solve as you point earlier. That's why i'm having a headache here. It's 3rd-grade math problem :( dafaq my country is thinking?

Comment: @Eddie just wondering, how are you so sure it is a third grade problem?

Comment: It's in one of their math exercise book.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are 136 solutions for this:

126478359   1   2   6   4   7   8   3   5   9   66

126478539   1   2   6   4   7   8   5   3   9   66

132458796   1   3   2   4   5   8   7   9   6   66

132458976   1   3   2   4   5   8   9   7   6   66

132956478   1   3   2   9   5   6   4   7   8   66

132956748   1   3   2   9   5   6   7   4   8   66

134765298   1   3   4   7   6   5   2   9   8   66

134765928   1   3   4   7   6   5   9   2   8   66

136279458   1   3   6   2   7   9   4   5   8   66

136279548   1   3   6   2   7   9   5   4   8   66

139478256   1   3   9   4   7   8   2   5   6   66

139478526   1   3   9   4   7   8   5   2   6   66

148279356   1   4   8   2   7   9   3   5   6   66

148279536   1   4   8   2   7   9   5   3   6   66

152348796   1   5   2   3   4   8   7   9   6   66

152348976   1   5   2   3   4   8   9   7   6   66

152847396   1   5   2   8   4   7   3   9   6   66

152847936   1   5   2   8   4   7   9   3   6   66

153942786   1   5   3   9   4   2   7   8   6   66

153942876   1   5   3   9   4   2   8   7   6   66

183745269   1   8   3   7   4   5   2   6   9   66

183745629   1   8   3   7   4   5   6   2   9   66

196458372   1   9   6   4   5   8   3   7   2   66

196458732   1   9   6   4   5   8   7   3   2   66

196752348   1   9   6   7   5   2   3   4   8   66

196752438   1   9   6   7   5   2   4   3   8   66

214379568   2   1   4   3   7   9   5   6   8   66

214379658   2   1   4   3   7   9   6   5   8   66

236179458   2   3   6   1   7   9   4   5   8   66

236179548   2   3   6   1   7   9   5   4   8   66

248179356   2   4   8   1   7   9   3   5   6   66

248179536   2   4   8   1   7   9   5   3   6   66

269851473   2   6   9   8   5   1   4   7   3   66

269851743   2   6   9   8   5   1   7   4   3   66

286941573   2   8   6   9   4   1   5   7   3   66

286941753   2   8   6   9   4   1   7   5   3   66

296351478   2   9   6   3   5   1   4   7   8   66

296351748   2   9   6   3   5   1   7   4   8   66

314279568   3   1   4   2   7   9   5   6   8   66

314279658   3   1   4   2   7   9   6   5   8   66

321547896   3   2   1   5   4   7   8   9   6   66

321547986   3   2   1   5   4   7   9   8   6   66

324851796   3   2   4   8   5   1   7   9   6   66

324851976   3   2   4   8   5   1   9   7   6   66

328651794   3   2   8   6   5   1   7   9   4   66

328651974   3   2   8   6   5   1   9   7   4   66

352148796   3   5   2   1   4   8   7   9   6   66

352148976   3   5   2   1   4   8   9   7   6   66

364958172   3   6   4   9   5   8   1   7   2   66

364958712   3   6   4   9   5   8   7   1   2   66

392815674   3   9   2   8   1   5   6   7   4   66

392815764   3   9   2   8   1   5   7   6   4   66

396251478   3   9   6   2   5   1   4   7   8   66

396251748   3   9   6   2   5   1   7   4   8   66

426178359   4   2   6   1   7   8   3   5   9   66

426178539   4   2   6   1   7   8   5   3   9   66

432158796   4   3   2   1   5   8   7   9   6   66

432158976   4   3   2   1   5   8   9   7   6   66

439178256   4   3   9   1   7   8   2   5   6   66

439178526   4   3   9   1   7   8   5   2   6   66

496158372   4   9   6   1   5   8   3   7   2   66

496158732   4   9   6   1   5   8   7   3   2   66

512967348   5   1   2   9   6   7   3   4   8   66

512967438   5   1   2   9   6   7   4   3   8   66

521347896   5   2   1   3   4   7   8   9   6   66

521347986   5   2   1   3   4   7   9   8   6   66

531726894   5   3   1   7   2   6   8   9   4   66

531726984   5   3   1   7   2   6   9   8   4   66

541927386   5   4   1   9   2   7   3   8   6   66

541927836   5   4   1   9   2   7   8   3   6   66

548967132   5   4   8   9   6   7   1   3   2   66

548967312   5   4   8   9   6   7   3   1   2   66

572839164   5   7   2   8   3   9   1   6   4   66

572839614   5   7   2   8   3   9   6   1   4   66

593621784   5   9   3   6   2   1   7   8   4   66

593621874   5   9   3   6   2   1   8   7   4   66

628351794   6   2   8   3   5   1   7   9   4   66

628351974   6   2   8   3   5   1   9   7   4   66

631925784   6   3   1   9   2   5   7   8   4   66

631925874   6   3   1   9   2   5   8   7   4   66

693521784   6   9   3   5   2   1   7   8   4   66

693521874   6   9   3   5   2   1   8   7   4   66

714965238   7   1   4   9   6   5   2   3   8   66

714965328   7   1   4   9   6   5   3   2   8   66

728965134   7   2   8   9   6   5   1   3   4   66

728965314   7   2   8   9   6   5   3   1   4   66

731526894   7   3   1   5   2   6   8   9   4   66

731526984   7   3   1   5   2   6   9   8   4   66

732859164   7   3   2   8   5   9   1   6   4   66

732859614   7   3   2   8   5   9   6   1   4   66

734165298   7   3   4   1   6   5   2   9   8   66

734165928   7   3   4   1   6   5   9   2   8   66

752849136   7   5   2   8   4   9   1   3   6   66

752849316   7   5   2   8   4   9   3   1   6   66

764859132   7   6   4   8   5   9   1   3   2   66

764859312   7   6   4   8   5   9   3   1   2   66

783145269   7   8   3   1   4   5   2   6   9   66

783145629   7   8   3   1   4   5   6   2   9   66

796152348   7   9   6   1   5   2   3   4   8   66

796152438   7   9   6   1   5   2   4   3   8   66

824351796   8   2   4   3   5   1   7   9   6   66

824351976   8   2   4   3   5   1   9   7   6   66

832759164   8   3   2   7   5   9   1   6   4   66

832759614   8   3   2   7   5   9   6   1   4   66

852147396   8   5   2   1   4   7   3   9   6   66

852147936   8   5   2   1   4   7   9   3   6   66

852749136   8   5   2   7   4   9   1   3   6   66

852749316   8   5   2   7   4   9   3   1   6   66

864759132   8   6   4   7   5   9   1   3   2   66

864759312   8   6   4   7   5   9   3   1   2   66

869251473   8   6   9   2   5   1   4   7   3   66

869251743   8   6   9   2   5   1   7   4   3   66

872539164   8   7   2   5   3   9   1   6   4   66

872539614   8   7   2   5   3   9   6   1   4   66

892315674   8   9   2   3   1   5   6   7   4   66

892315764   8   9   2   3   1   5   7   6   4   66

912567348   9   1   2   5   6   7   3   4   8   66

912567438   9   1   2   5   6   7   4   3   8   66

914765238   9   1   4   7   6   5   2   3   8   66

914765328   9   1   4   7   6   5   3   2   8   66

928765134   9   2   8   7   6   5   1   3   4   66

928765314   9   2   8   7   6   5   3   1   4   66

931625784   9   3   1   6   2   5   7   8   4   66

931625874   9   3   1   6   2   5   8   7   4   66

932156478   9   3   2   1   5   6   4   7   8   66

932156748   9   3   2   1   5   6   7   4   8   66

941527386   9   4   1   5   2   7   3   8   6   66

941527836   9   4   1   5   2   7   8   3   6   66

948567132   9   4   8   5   6   7   1   3   2   66

948567312   9   4   8   5   6   7   3   1   2   66

953142786   9   5   3   1   4   2   7   8   6   66

953142876   9   5   3   1   4   2   8   7   6   66

964358172   9   6   4   3   5   8   1   7   2   66

964358712   9   6   4   3   5   8   7   1   2   66

986241573   9   8   6   2   4   1   5   7   3   66

986241753   9   8   6   2   4   1   7   5   3   66

I used c++ and Excel to solve it.

Check the solution here:

https://github.com/jpruiz114/cpp-tests/tree/master/DevCppTest02

Comment: I love how you store it on github :)

Comment: MAAAANNNN, where do you from? How did you extract all the information and write a complete documentation of this math problem? You're my idol!

Comment: Hey Eddie, from the US, based in South America. There's a document for this, is here: http://issuu.com/jpruiz114/docs/brute_force_solution_for_vietnamese

Feel free to touch base with me via email.

Answer (score 3):

I assume that (as usual in this type of problem) the operations are executed left toright (not by arithemtic priority). Here are the solutions:

- [9, 4, 8, 6, 7, 3, 1, 2, 5]: $9+13=22$, $22\times 4=88$, $88:8=11$, $11+6=17$, $17+12=29$, $29\times 7=203$, $203-3=200$, $200-11=189$, $189+1=190$, $190\times 2=380$, $380:5=76$, $76-10=66$.
- [9, 7, 2, 8, 4, 3, 6, 1, 5]
- [9, 6, 3, 8, 5, 7, 2, 1, 4]
- [9, 1, 4, 8, 2, 7, 5, 6, 3]
- [9, 5, 3, 8, 1, 2, 7, 6, 4]
- [9, 2, 4, 7, 8, 6, 5, 1, 3]
- [9, 3, 2, 4, 8, 7, 6, 1, 5]
- [9, 3, 2, 7, 6, 5, 8, 1, 4]
- [9, 5, 3, 7, 1, 2, 8, 6, 4]
- [9, 4, 3, 5, 2, 1, 8, 6, 7]
- [9, 3, 2, 6, 1, 7, 5, 8, 4]
- [9, 3, 2, 5, 1, 7, 6, 8, 4]
- [8, 9, 7, 1, 4, 2, 5, 3, 6]
- [7, 9, 8, 5, 6, 2, 4, 1, 3]
- [7, 9, 4, 8, 6, 2, 3, 1, 5]
- [7, 9, 5, 8, 3, 6, 1, 2, 4]
- [2, 9, 4, 3, 8, 6, 7, 1, 5]
- [7, 9, 5, 6, 1, 8, 3, 4, 2]
- [7, 9, 5, 3, 1, 8, 6, 4, 2]
- [1, 9, 7, 5, 2, 8, 6, 4, 3]
- [1, 9, 7, 3, 5, 8, 6, 2, 4]
- [3, 9, 6, 5, 4, 8, 7, 1, 2]
- [6, 9, 3, 1, 4, 8, 5, 2, 7]
- [1, 9, 3, 7, 2, 5, 8, 4, 6]
- [1, 9, 6, 2, 3, 7, 8, 4, 5]
- [4, 9, 3, 2, 6, 7, 8, 1, 5]
- [3, 9, 4, 6, 5, 1, 8, 2, 7]
- [2, 9, 5, 7, 1, 3, 6, 8, 4]
- [2, 9, 5, 6, 1, 3, 7, 8, 4]
- [7, 9, 5, 6, 3, 1, 2, 4, 8]
- [1, 9, 7, 2, 5, 3, 6, 4, 8]
- [8, 6, 9, 7, 5, 3, 1, 2, 4]
- [8, 3, 9, 5, 7, 6, 1, 2, 4]
- [8, 6, 9, 5, 2, 1, 7, 4, 3]
- [8, 5, 9, 3, 6, 4, 7, 1, 2]
- [8, 1, 9, 3, 4, 2, 7, 6, 5]
- [8, 6, 9, 3, 5, 2, 1, 4, 7]
- [8, 5, 9, 1, 4, 2, 3, 6, 7]
- [5, 4, 9, 1, 8, 7, 2, 3, 6]
- [5, 4, 9, 1, 6, 8, 7, 2, 3]
- [5, 4, 9, 3, 7, 6, 8, 1, 2]
- [5, 1, 9, 3, 7, 2, 8, 4, 6]
- [5, 6, 9, 7, 1, 4, 3, 8, 2]
- [5, 4, 9, 7, 1, 3, 6, 8, 2]
- [5, 6, 9, 3, 1, 4, 7, 8, 2]
- [5, 4, 9, 6, 1, 3, 7, 8, 2]
- [5, 1, 9, 2, 3, 6, 7, 8, 4]
- [5, 4, 9, 1, 3, 2, 7, 8, 6]
- [5, 1, 9, 2, 4, 3, 7, 8, 6]
- [7, 3, 9, 4, 5, 2, 1, 6, 8]
- [5, 7, 9, 1, 6, 2, 3, 4, 8]
- [2, 6, 9, 1, 7, 3, 5, 4, 8]
- [8, 1, 7, 9, 2, 4, 5, 6, 3]
- [8, 4, 3, 9, 5, 7, 1, 2, 6]
- [8, 1, 3, 9, 5, 2, 6, 4, 7]
- [2, 8, 4, 9, 1, 7, 5, 6, 3]
- [5, 8, 6, 9, 1, 3, 7, 4, 2]
- [7, 6, 8, 9, 2, 5, 1, 4, 3]
- [5, 2, 4, 9, 8, 7, 6, 1, 3]
- [3, 1, 4, 9, 8, 6, 7, 2, 5]
- [7, 1, 3, 9, 6, 8, 5, 2, 4]
- [7, 1, 4, 9, 2, 8, 5, 6, 3]
- [5, 7, 6, 9, 4, 8, 3, 1, 2]
- [1, 7, 6, 9, 3, 8, 2, 4, 5]
- [5, 1, 6, 9, 7, 8, 3, 2, 4]
- [5, 4, 1, 9, 3, 8, 6, 2, 7]
- [4, 6, 3, 9, 7, 2, 8, 1, 5]
- [5, 1, 3, 9, 6, 7, 8, 2, 4]
- [5, 4, 3, 9, 6, 1, 8, 2, 7]
- [7, 3, 6, 9, 1, 5, 4, 8, 2]
- [7, 3, 4, 9, 2, 5, 1, 8, 6]
- [2, 7, 6, 9, 1, 4, 5, 8, 3]
- [2, 6, 3, 9, 1, 7, 5, 8, 4]
- [5, 3, 2, 9, 1, 6, 7, 8, 4]
- [7, 1, 3, 9, 6, 5, 2, 4, 8]
- [7, 3, 1, 9, 2, 5, 6, 4, 8]
- [8, 1, 7, 3, 9, 5, 6, 2, 4]
- [8, 4, 7, 3, 9, 5, 1, 2, 6]
- [8, 4, 6, 5, 9, 3, 1, 2, 7]
- [7, 4, 8, 5, 9, 6, 2, 1, 3]
- [7, 2, 8, 1, 9, 4, 5, 3, 6]
- [3, 4, 8, 7, 9, 5, 1, 2, 6]
- [7, 2, 6, 8, 9, 5, 4, 1, 3]
- [7, 1, 3, 8, 9, 5, 4, 2, 6]
- [3, 6, 4, 8, 9, 7, 2, 1, 5]
- [3, 1, 6, 8, 9, 7, 4, 2, 5]
- [7, 6, 4, 2, 9, 8, 3, 1, 5]
- [3, 7, 6, 5, 9, 8, 2, 1, 4]
- [1, 5, 7, 4, 9, 3, 8, 2, 6]
- [5, 1, 6, 3, 9, 7, 8, 2, 4]
- [3, 2, 6, 1, 9, 7, 5, 4, 8]
- [2, 1, 5, 3, 9, 6, 7, 4, 8]
- [1, 8, 6, 7, 3, 9, 2, 4, 5]
- [6, 8, 4, 5, 3, 9, 7, 1, 2]
- [7, 5, 8, 4, 2, 9, 1, 6, 3]
- [7, 2, 5, 1, 8, 9, 4, 3, 6]
- [1, 2, 7, 5, 8, 9, 4, 3, 6]
- [3, 5, 2, 7, 8, 9, 4, 1, 6]
- [1, 4, 7, 5, 2, 9, 8, 6, 3]
- [1, 4, 3, 7, 2, 9, 8, 6, 5]
- [2, 1, 5, 3, 7, 9, 8, 4, 6]
- [2, 7, 3, 6, 1, 9, 5, 8, 4]
- [2, 7, 3, 5, 1, 9, 6, 8, 4]
- [3, 7, 2, 5, 1, 9, 4, 8, 6]
- [3, 7, 2, 4, 1, 9, 5, 8, 6]
- [1, 4, 7, 5, 3, 9, 2, 8, 6]
- [6, 3, 4, 7, 2, 9, 1, 8, 5]
- [4, 1, 6, 7, 3, 9, 2, 8, 5]
- [5, 1, 6, 2, 3, 9, 7, 8, 4]
- [2, 5, 6, 4, 3, 9, 1, 8, 7]
- [6, 2, 1, 5, 3, 9, 7, 4, 8]
- [8, 1, 7, 5, 6, 4, 9, 2, 3]
- [5, 8, 6, 7, 1, 3, 9, 4, 2]
- [2, 8, 4, 5, 1, 7, 9, 6, 3]
- [1, 7, 8, 6, 4, 5, 9, 2, 3]
- [3, 6, 8, 7, 5, 1, 9, 2, 4]
- [1, 6, 7, 8, 2, 5, 9, 4, 3]
- [2, 1, 5, 8, 6, 3, 9, 4, 7]
- [2, 1, 6, 3, 8, 5, 9, 4, 7]
- [2, 6, 5, 4, 7, 8, 9, 1, 3]
- [7, 3, 6, 4, 1, 5, 9, 8, 2]
- [7, 2, 5, 1, 3, 4, 9, 8, 6]
- [2, 7, 6, 5, 1, 4, 9, 8, 3]
- [1, 3, 7, 5, 2, 6, 9, 8, 4]
- [1, 2, 7, 5, 3, 4, 9, 8, 6]
- [5, 3, 2, 7, 1, 6, 9, 8, 4]
- [2, 6, 3, 5, 1, 7, 9, 8, 4]
- [5, 2, 4, 1, 3, 7, 9, 8, 6]
- [3, 5, 4, 1, 2, 7, 9, 8, 6]
- [4, 5, 1, 7, 3, 6, 9, 2, 8]
- [7, 4, 6, 8, 1, 2, 5, 9, 3]
- [7, 4, 6, 5, 1, 2, 8, 9, 3]
- [8, 7, 3, 1, 2, 4, 5, 6, 9]
- [8, 2, 1, 7, 3, 6, 5, 4, 9]
- [8, 2, 1, 6, 3, 5, 7, 4, 9]
- [1, 8, 7, 2, 6, 3, 5, 4, 9]
- [1, 8, 4, 7, 5, 2, 6, 3, 9]
- [5, 8, 3, 1, 2, 4, 7, 6, 9]
- [3, 7, 8, 5, 4, 1, 2, 6, 9]
- [7, 1, 2, 8, 6, 3, 5, 4, 9]
- [7, 2, 1, 8, 4, 6, 5, 3, 9]
- [1, 4, 2, 8, 5, 7, 6, 3, 9]
- [3, 1, 4, 8, 5, 2, 7, 6, 9]
- [5, 7, 4, 1, 8, 6, 3, 2, 9]
- [2, 1, 3, 6, 8, 7, 5, 4, 9]
- [7, 1, 2, 4, 5, 8, 3, 6, 9]
- [4, 6, 1, 7, 2, 8, 5, 3, 9]
- [1, 2, 4, 7, 5, 8, 3, 6, 9]
- [2, 3, 5, 6, 7, 8, 1, 4, 9]
- [4, 6, 1, 5, 2, 7, 8, 3, 9]
- [2, 7, 6, 4, 3, 5, 1, 8, 9]
- [2, 1, 6, 4, 5, 3, 7, 8, 9]

Comment: I've just read your answer more closely. Probably you're right, it's not using arithmetic priority. But what if they does? Because grouping using priority reduce the solutions.

Comment: @HagenvonEitzen: A commenter on this [Huffingtonpost article](http://www.huffingtonpost.com/2015/05/20/vietnamese-math-puzzle_n_7346332.html?ncid=txtlnkusaolp00000592) also arrived at the total of 152 solutions. Apparently, the puzzle was created by Tan Phuong of Vietnam.

Comment: @TitoPiezasIII Look at my answer. There are only 20 solutions. probably the other commenter was wrong, or didn't use mathematic priority. Or my algorithm is not correct? Can you check it at stackOverflow?

Comment: @Eddie: More accurately, if you use one assumption, you get 152 solutions. If you use another, you have just 20 solutions. It depends on how the problem was originally stated.

Answer (score 2):

There is 1 equation and 9 unknowns, the problem is we have an underdetermined system: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Underdetermined_system.

The only relationship we know (in the typical phrasing of the question) is that they all belong to the set [1...9] and are mutually exclusive. While all solutions can be found using brute force (with a program), I don't believe there is a mathematical way to prove or derive the existence of any solutions since the placement of any number impacts the choices for the remaining numbers and the information is too limited. We know without brute forcing that the system has at most a limited number of solutions. We know from running programs (only after the fact) that the puzzle is consistent and has solutions.

a + d - f + 12*e + 13*b/c + g*h/j = 87

The values of a and d are interchangeable, as are g and h. It does not help us with the problem, but it does show that if at least 1 solution exists, then more than 1 solution must exist; specifically, if you find 1 it has 4 variants since some of the math is commutative.

Comment: So, to summarize, you're saying that there are no mathematical solution to this problem? Brute force is the only way?

Answer (score 1):

I ask [StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30310415/find-a-math-algorithm-for-an-equation) for a programmatic solution, turn out having 20 answer:

```
2015-05-20 01:44:23.568 Math[29526:3757225] a=3 b=2 c=1 d=5 e=4 f=7 g=8 h=9 i=6
2015-05-20 01:44:23.569 Math[29526:3757225] a=3 b=2 c=1 d=5 e=4 f=7 g=9 h=8 i=6
2015-05-20 01:44:24.074 Math[29526:3757225] a=5 b=2 c=1 d=3 e=4 f=7 g=8 h=9 i=6
2015-05-20 01:44:24.075 Math[29526:3757225] a=5 b=2 c=1 d=3 e=4 f=7 g=9 h=8 i=6
2015-05-20 01:44:24.127 Math[29526:3757225] a=5 b=3 c=1 d=7 e=2 f=6 g=8 h=9 i=4
2015-05-20 01:44:24.127 Math[29526:3757225] a=5 b=3 c=1 d=7 e=2 f=6 g=9 h=8 i=4
2015-05-20 01:44:24.162 Math[29526:3757225] a=5 b=4 c=1 d=9 e=2 f=7 g=3 h=8 i=6
2015-05-20 01:44:24.163 Math[29526:3757225] a=5 b=4 c=1 d=9 e=2 f=7 g=8 h=3 i=6
2015-05-20 01:44:24.290 Math[29526:3757225] a=5 b=9 c=3 d=6 e=2 f=1 g=7 h=8 i=4
2015-05-20 01:44:24.290 Math[29526:3757225] a=5 b=9 c=3 d=6 e=2 f=1 g=8 h=7 i=4
2015-05-20 01:44:24.381 Math[29526:3757225] a=6 b=3 c=1 d=9 e=2 f=5 g=7 h=8 i=4
2015-05-20 01:44:24.381 Math[29526:3757225] a=6 b=3 c=1 d=9 e=2 f=5 g=8 h=7 i=4
2015-05-20 01:44:24.548 Math[29526:3757225] a=6 b=9 c=3 d=5 e=2 f=1 g=7 h=8 i=4
2015-05-20 01:44:24.548 Math[29526:3757225] a=6 b=9 c=3 d=5 e=2 f=1 g=8 h=7 i=4
2015-05-20 01:44:24.630 Math[29526:3757225] a=7 b=3 c=1 d=5 e=2 f=6 g=8 h=9 i=4
2015-05-20 01:44:24.630 Math[29526:3757225] a=7 b=3 c=1 d=5 e=2 f=6 g=9 h=8 i=4
2015-05-20 01:44:25.115 Math[29526:3757225] a=9 b=3 c=1 d=6 e=2 f=5 g=7 h=8 i=4
2015-05-20 01:44:25.115 Math[29526:3757225] a=9 b=3 c=1 d=6 e=2 f=5 g=8 h=7 i=4
2015-05-20 01:44:25.143 Math[29526:3757225] a=9 b=4 c=1 d=5 e=2 f=7 g=3 h=8 i=6
2015-05-20 01:44:25.143 Math[29526:3757225] a=9 b=4 c=1 d=5 e=2 f=7 g=8 h=3 i=6
2015-05-20 01:44:25.294 Math[29526:3757225] Result: 20 correct / 362880 total
```

Not sure how it will look like as a mathematic problem.

Comment: that's incorrect, there are 136 solutions ... someone clearly didn't pay attention to floating operations ... here is a python script - https://repl.it/oxA/7