# How to tame a Rechenschlange

Tags: puzzle

I found the following problem, called *Rechenschlange* (literal translation: *calculation snake*) in a German puzzle calendar:

> Fill the blanks with the numbers 1-9. Each number must only appear once. All operators are evaluated left to right.
>
> ```
>  xx      xx  :  xx      14
>   +       +      +       =
>  10      11     12      13
>   -       +      -       -
>  xx      xx     xx      xx
>   *  xx   :      *  xx   +
> ```

<sub>(Source: Harenberg Denksport 9. Mai 2014)</sub>

In other words:

$(((((((((((a + 10) - b) * c) / d) + 11) + e) / f) + 12) - g) * h) + i - 13 = 14$

or

$ \big(\frac{\frac{(a + 10 - b)c}{d} + 11 + e}{f} + 12 - g\big)h + i = 27$

**How would I approach this problem mathematically?**

---

My thoughts so far:

- Just (manual) trial and error is not an option, since there are $9! = 362880$ permutations.
- I tried to reduce the search space by going backwards from the result, but, so far, I only managed to deduce that $h \neq 9$. Which means I have only $8! * 8$ permutations left. Great! Then I got stuck.
- The puzzle calendar's puzzles are usually not very hard (crosswords and number pyramids), so I doubt that the intended solution involves high-level number theory. There's a solution at the back of the puzzle sheet, but no explanation on how to get it.
- Maybe there's more than one solution? Maybe there are so many solutions that trial and error is actually the right approach? For fun, I wrote a small script to solve this, which returned 377 unique $(a, ..., i)$ tuples. That's about 1 in 1000, so that can't be the intended solution either.

Comment: Related: ["A 3rd grade math problem: fill in blanks with numbers to obtain a valid equation"](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/1288170/409). The numbers and arrangement of operations are different, but the answers may be helpful.

Answer (score 1):

Unless there's some other unstated constraint, the problem doesn't have a unique solution. Even if you demand an integer at every step of the calculation, you get 301 distinct $(a,\ldots,i)$ tuples that qualify. My guess is that the constructor didn't realize (or care) that there is more than one solution.  Writing a small script would be the quickest way to generate all solutions.